# How use refactoring tools when you have multiple visual studio solutions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring

We have two visual studio solutions for our product: one for our reusable components (Core.sln) and one for our product (Product.sln). Projects from the Product solution have references (file references) to assemblies of our core.

When working in one solution, the refactoring features will not refractor in the other solution. Renaming a method in a core class renames it in the Core solution but not in the Product solution.

Is there a way to benefit from refactoring tools when using multiple solutions? Do commercial refactoring products (Resharper, Code Rush) have the same limitation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a solution that references all relevant projects in order to do this.

Yes, commercial refactoring products has the same limitation. After all, how should the tool know, that you, somewhere on your disk drive, has a .csproj and some .cs file lying around, that references a specific method name ?

Comment: This is what I do. I have one huge solution where I do any core refactoring, and other smaller, project specific ones where I do most of my daily work.

Comment: I have the feeling that this is very basic scenario. I think tools (including VS) should have an option to configure "Search paths".

Comment: You have a point, it would be nice. But you also have to remember that code that needs to be changed might not even be on your local machine. Perhaps one of the Product.sln projects added by another developer only exists in the source control system, when you try to refactor Core.sln.

Comment: will also give you the bonus of hazzle free switching from debug to release builds